# checked out version doesn't match glide.lock

Tags: git, github, glide-golang

i checked out a Golang project using glide, and there is a glide.lock file in the repo.

```
>>git clone https://github.com/uber/aresdb
>>cd aresdb/
>>git checkout v0.0.1
>>glide i
...
[INFO]  --> Found desired version locally gopkg.in/fsnotify/fsnotify.v1 
c2828203cd70a50dcccfb2761f8b1f8ceef9a8e9!
...
```

fsnotify version defined in https://github.com/uber/aresdb/blob/v0.0.1/glide.lock is the following:

```
- name: gopkg.in/fsnotify/fsnotify.v1
  version: c2828203cd70a50dcccfb2761f8b1f8ceef9a8e9
```

So I understand the following revision of fsnotify (v1.4.7) will be used

https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify/commit/c2828203cd70a50dcccfb2761f8b1f8ceef9a8e9

which is

https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify/releases/tag/v1.4.7

however, when i look at the following file from my checkout,

```
vendor/github.com/hpcloud/tail/vendor/gopkg.in/fsnotify/fsnotify.v1/AUTHORS
```

it is different than https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify/blob/v1.4.7/AUTHORS

it seems to be showing an older version (https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify/blob/v1.2.1/AUTHORS)

how should troubleshoot this? or am I misunderstanding how glide.lock works?

thanks!

regards,

SQR

Answer (score 0):

okay, there were multiple copies introduced by indirect dependencies; I was looking at the wrong file.

Here is the relevant copy:

```
vendor/gopkg.in/fsnotify/fsnotify.v1
```